# docker add command fails to add the path passed as argument to it

Tags: docker, jenkins, arguments, docker-build

I have a `Dockerfile` which I want to be built and pushed after jenkins maven build. I have these lines in my `Dockerfile`:

```
...
ARG MAIN_DIR
ADD $MAIN_DIR .
...
```

And I pass `MAIN_DIR` argument as follows:

```
docker build -t my.gitlab.com:4567/path/to/my/project/my-image-name:my-image-tag --build-arg MAIN_DIR=Development .
```

But I get:

```
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder832988213/Development: no such file or directory
```

**EDIT 1:**

`COPY $MAIN_DIR .` generates the same issue.

**EDIT 2:**

Current directory actually contains a directory named `Development` and I'm completely sure there is no `.dockerignore` file in the whole project.

Comment: Does the fodler where the command gets executed has a directory named Development ? You may be running your build in wrong directory or Development folder may not be there

Comment: @TarunLalwani, yes, it does; but `Development` is not under `/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder832988213/`.

Comment: That is because build creates and new directory and send all the date over there. One other thing I can suspect is a presence of `.dockerignore` not letting that directory be send to daemon. Or other wise it being name `development` and not `Development`. Docker is case sensitive

Comment: @TarunLalwani, there is no `.dockerignore`

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong which is just getting ignored by your eyes

Comment: @TarunLalwani, actually that is why I'm asking :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152936/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-zeinab-abbasi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our chat discussion the Dockerfile you are using is under the Development directory and you are using below to build the image

```
docker build -t my.gitlab.com:4567/path/to/my/project/my-image-name:my-image-tag --build-arg MAIN_DIR=Development --build-arg VERSION=1.0.0 path/to/Docker/context/dir
```

your `pwd` is

```
/home/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Project-Name
```

So when you send the context directory as the one containing the Dockerfile, then only content of that directory is sent to the docker daemon as context. And the development folder is in the parent hierarchy. So you won't be able to access anything that is above or outside the context folder.

Solution is to use a context directory which is separate from the Dockerfile

```
docker build -t my.gitlab.com:4567/path/to/my/project/my-image-name:my-image-tag --build-arg MAIN_DIR=Development --build-arg VERSION=1.0.0 -f path/to/docker/directory/Dockerfile path/to/projectdirectory
```